# 'ionic build android' command fails in windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I have started development with ionic framework.
I had installed almost all the requirements which are recommended to start development with ionic framework.
but when i tried to build the sample project it gives me an error as the screen shot shows or as bellow

```
D:\TenDril\ionic\todo>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
D:\TenDril\ionic\todo\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
D:\TenDril\ionic\todo
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=E:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
  >   Required by:
  >       :android:unspecified
  >   Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/g
  >       radle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
  >   repo1.maven.org

  ```
  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED
  Total time: 22.372 secs
  Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\TenDril\ionic\todo\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\TenDril\ionic\todo\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
  ```

[image]

Comment: Do you have your platform created?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try config.xml->Platforms checked Use Globally installed Cordova version

[image]

Comment: i am sorry to ask you this normal question,
Where is the config.xml is located????

Comment: in your project folder. I guess below of the www folder

Comment: When you work behind the proxy

always the connection problem occurred to work with ionic, cordova, git commands for those commands which interact with the outer network.

for this kind of the solution do set all configuration in cmd which you required.

npm config set proxy url:port
npm config set http-proxy url:port
npm config set https-proxy url:port

git config --system --add http.proxy url:port
git config --global --add http.proxy url:port

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual solution.....

the problem is that i am behind the proxy and the properties for the proxy is not match so the problem was occurred.

To define the proxy setting you have to create the **gradle.properties**

Create this gradle.properties file at ***C:\Users[YOUR-PC].gradle*** as below with your detail

---

- systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.0.1
- systemProp.http.proxyPort=808
- systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.0.1
- systemProp.https.proxyPort=808

you can set other properties for your machine in this gradle.properties file.
for more detail visit https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Answer (score 0):

When you work behind the proxy

always the connection problem occurred to work with ionic, cordova, git commands for those commands which interact with the outer network.

for this kind of the solution do set all configuration in cmd which you required.

---

### Please use -g option for global setting for nodejs, cordova | git and other

> Proxy for NodeJS

- npm config set proxy url:port
- npm config set http-proxy url:port
- npm config set https-proxy url:port

> Proxy for Cordova | git

- git config --system --add http.proxy url:port
- git config --global --add http.proxy url:port
- git config --system --add https.proxy url:port
- git config --global --add https.proxy url:port

> Proxy for other commands

- set proxy=url:port
- set http-proxy=url:port
- set https-proxy=url:port